# pfSense 2.3.2 cannot install Squid and SquidGuard

Tags: freebsd, squid, pfsense, freebsd-ports

pfSense 2.3.2 is newly installed but it gives the following error during the Squid and SquidGuard installation.

```
Number of packages to be installed: 4

The process will require 10 MiB more space.
[1/4] Installing squid-3.5.19...
===> Creating groups.
Using existing group 'squid'.
===> Creating users
Using existing user 'squid'.
install: not found
pkg: PRE-INSTALL script failed
Failed
```

Comment: I have resolved my issue ref link https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/6643

Answer (score 1):

According to the [pfSense forums](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=120921.0) (dead link as of 2024) the fix for this is:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/squid/
```

I can confirm it for upgrade from `2.1.5-RELEASE` (amd64) to `2.3.2-RELEASE-p1` (amd64) and then using package manager to install Squid Proxy.

After removing the directory above I could install the package. Only needed to clear the cache via “Services -> Squid Proxy -> Local Cache -> Clear Disk Cache NOW” to enable the service.